# Recommendations for making bench more sturdy?

Tags: strength, weight-capacity, stability

My first home woodwork project was this bench/bookcase. It is pretty sturdy but wobbles a little. I would like to reinforce it on the back but would love some guidance on what would be best. It currently has two brace joints at each end and four connectors on the middle support. [image]

Dimensions are H19.5in. by L8ft by W11.5in

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. We could do with some more details on what you have already (the "two brace joints" are unknowns to us), but tacking on a complete back to this would basically solve all 'parallelogramming' in one simple operation.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting a couple triangles in a couple corners on the back would stiffen it up A LOT.  as long as the triangles were well fastened to both a vertical and horizontal piece.  Even some 1/4" veneered plywood would work well.

Comment: <sigh> An edit to your Answer and still my upvote is the only one. The lack of voting engagement here is getting to be chronic!

Comment: @Graphus I must admit my engagement with the site ebbs and flows, but when I read good answers (and questions) I do tend to up vote.  It's also summer, and people tend to spend more time outdoors...

Comment: It's not linked to low visitation as it's been part of a consistent trend (going back further than I thought judging by some Questions *and* Answers from '19 and '20 that I spotted at random recently with far too few votes). But apparently the problem with low voting rates is endemic to all of SE. Hence the powers that be decided to go forward with the minor tweak that changed the arrows from grey to black, which they tell us made a significant difference during testing........ we'll see how that plays out!